# Error running ASR health status report Kusto query

Tags: azure, kql

I am trying to query replication health of all protected Azure VMs and break them down into three states: normal, warning and critical. But I got an error running below code:

```
AzureDiagnostics  
| where replicationProviderName_s == "A2A"   
| where isnotempty(name_s) and isnotnull(name_s)  
| summarize hint.strategy=partitioned arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by name_s  
| project name_s , replicationHealth_s  
| summarize count() by replicationHealth_s  
| render piechart
```

Error is: ***'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar ex;pression named 'replicationProviderName_S'***

Please help me resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error means there's no column named `replicationProviderName_s` in the schema of the table/function named `AzureDiagnostics`.

what does the following return when you run it?

`AzureDiagnostics | getschema`